# Cannot set an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, sequence

I'm using the `NumPy` python library to run large-scale edits on a `.csv` file. I'm using this python code:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    try:
        e,a,ad,c,s,z,ca,fn,ln,p,p2,g,ssn,cn,com,dob,doh,em = np.loadtxt('c:\wamp\www\_quac\carryover_data\SI\Employees.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str')

        x=0
        dob = dob.split('/')
        for digit in dob:
            if len(digit) == 1:
                digit = str('0'+digit)
        dob = str(dob[2]+'-'+dob[0]+'-'+dob[1])

        doh = doh.split('/')
        for digit in doh:
            if len(digit) == 1:
                digit = str('0'+digit)
        doh = str(doh[2]+'-'+doh[0]+'-'+doh[1])

        for eID in e:
            saveLine=eID+','+a[x]+','+ad[x]+','+c[x]+','+s[x]+','+z[x]+','+ca[x]+','+fn[x]+','+ln[x]+','+p[x]+','+p2[x]+','+g[x]+','+ssn[x]+','+cn[x]+','+com[x]+','+dob[x]+','+doh[x]+','+em[x]+'\n'
            saveFile = open('fixedEmployees.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(saveLine)
            saveFile.close()
            x+=1


    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

main()
```

`dob` and `doh` contain a string, e.g. `4/26/2012` and I'm trying to convert these to `mysql` friendly `DATE` forms, e.g. `2012-04-26`. The error that is printed when I run this script is

`cannot set an array element with a sequence`

It does not specify a line and so I don't know what this really means. I'm pretty new to python; I've checked other questions with this same error but I can't make sense of their code. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: also: perhaps this would be more easily done in excel? How could I do that?

Comment: Please remove the `try: except` clause and re-run your code to get the line and traceback for the error.

Comment: @ebarr doing so pointed me to the line with `e,a,ad,c,s,z,ca,fn,ln,p,p2` etc. and cited the same exact error...

Comment: If you don't use a tuple unpack on the `np.loadtxt` command, does it execute without error?

Comment: @ebarr yeah, it still did. I managed to get things to work although it was somehwhat of a workaround. I'm posting the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to solve it I had to do a couple things. After removing the `try`-`except` commands, I found out that the error was on line 5, the line with `e,a,ad,c,s` etc. I couldn't eliminate the problem until I simply copied the **2 columns I wanted to focus on *only*** and made a new program for dealing with those.

Then I had to create a `.txt` instead of a `.csv` because Excel auto-formats the dates and literally changes the values before I can even touch them. There is no way around that, I've learned. You can't turn the date-auto-format off. A serious problem with excel. So here's my solution for this `NumPy` script (it changes the first column and keeps the second the same):

```
import numpy as np
def main():
    dob,doh=np.loadtxt('temp.csv',
                             delimiter=',',
                             unpack=True,
                             dtype='str')


    x=0
    for eachDate in dob:
        if any(c.isalpha() for c in eachDate):
            newDate=eachDate
        elif (eachDate == ''):
            newDate=''
        else:
            sp = eachDate.split('/')
            y=0
            ndArray = ['','','']
            for eachDig in sp:
                if len(eachDig) == 1:
                    eachDig = str('0'+eachDig)
                if y == 0:
                    ndArray[0] = eachDig
                elif y == 1:
                    ndArray[1] = eachDig
                elif y == 2:
                    ndArray[2] = eachDig
                    newDate=str(ndArray[2]+'-'+ndArray[0]+'-'+ndArray[1])
                    y=0
                y+=1

        print eachDate+'--->'+newDate

        """creates a .txt file with the edited dates"""
        saveLine=str(newDate+','+doh[x]+'\n')
        saveFile=open('__newTemp.txt','a')
        saveFile.write(saveLine)
        saveFile.close()
        x+=1


main()
```

I then used Data->Import from text with "TEXT" format option in Excel to get the column into my `.csv`. I realize this is probably bulky and noobish but it got the job done :3

Comment: To summarize, I believe one of my columns in the original excel file was incompatible with `numpy`'s `loadtxt()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `zfill` to reformat the date string so you can have a '0' before your '4'. (`zfill` pads a string on the left with zeros to fill the width.)

```
doh = '4/26/2012'
doh = doh.split('/')

for i, s in enumerate(doh):
    doh[i] = s.zfill(2)

doh = doh[2]+'-'+doh[0]+'-'+doh[1]

# result: '2012-04-26'
```

As for the `cannot set an array element with a sequence` it would be helpful to know 
where that is occurring. I'm guessing there is something wrong with structure of the array.